# pagebackref option is not working in Beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, hyperref, back-referencing

When I use `\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}` in `\documentclass{article}`, it works perfectly. But when I use it in `beamer` class i.e. `\documentclass[hyperref={pagebackref=true}]{beamer}`, it does not work and no error is displayed. My task is to include the page numbers where the reference is cited in the bibliography produced by `beamer`. Please advise how I can achieve my task.

the following example is working perfectly

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{Sweave}

\begin{document}
Antecedent to 1970, Luce and Tukey's \cite{Luce1964} present first article on conjoint. Explain the relation between consumer's decision and the factors involved in his/ her decision making \cite{Orme2010}. In 1971, Green and Rao's joint effort of card-sort conjoint analysis \cite{Green1971} gained success beyond imagination. In 1975, Green and Wind \cite{Green1975} described the measures consumer judgments for carpet cleaners, and business leaders, this new method was soon taken into consideration.

\bibliographystyle{Ieeetr}
\bibliography{References/conjoint}

\end{document}
```

but when I used the following

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pagebackref=true,colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,pagebackref=true}]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[square, numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}

\begin{document}
\justifying

\section{Conjoint Analysis }
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Conjoint Analysis} 
Antecedent to 1970, Luce and Tukey's \cite{Luce1964} present first article on conjoint. Explain the relation between consumer's decision and the factors involved in his/ her decision making \cite{Orme2010}. In 1971, Green and Rao's joint effort of card-sort conjoint analysis \cite{Green1971} gained success beyond imagination. In 1975, Green and Wind \cite{Green1975} described the measures consumer judgments for carpet cleaners, and business leaders, this new method was soon taken into consideration.
\end{frame}

\bibliographystyle{Ieeetr}
\bibliography{References/conjoint}

\end{document}
```

no error found, but I am unable to find the page number in the bibliography to go-back at the page where it was cited as done in article class in first example.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). (I used these advice to edit your question.)

Comment: Please note that there is no reason for beamer to implement this and also it's not recommended. It's the presenter's responsibility to keep track of the presentation and also the bibliography in beamer is just suggestive and only for convenience. There must be a proper structure such that you don't need to use this. At worst you can use Alt+Right arrow to jump back to the original slide on AcroRead and SumatraPDF otherwise you can use the well-documented navigational symbols in your presentation.

Comment: My references are hyper link with research journal, so I need the path text to citation to research paper to reference to bank at text, hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 3):

As is mentioned in the comments, this is something which is simply not implemented in `beamer`. Support for bibliographies in the class is limited, and reflects the fact that presentations are not good places for such things.

Answer (score 1):

Answers along the lines *"you should not want that feature"* make me sad. Usually the OP has a reason to require that feature...and the same desire brought me here.

I think I found a solution - although I have not tested it extensively.

The problem seems to be that `hyperref` is loaded inside of `beamer` (and here as part of  `\documentclass`). Thus, configuring some of the options of `hyperref` later in the document using `\hypersetup` works for *some* options of `hyperref` but not for all. It looks like this is the case here: `hyperref` patches the reference system as part of its loading, and when later the respective options are set, there is no way to tell `hyperref` to redo this patching process.

For this sequencing issue there is `\PassOptionsToPackage` which can be used before `\documentclass`.

My solution is to place

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{pagebackref=true}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{backref=slide}{hyperref}
```

before `\documentclass` and then the whole thing works nicely.

**Bug:** My solution only works partially. It prints the backlinks in the bibliography, but (a) the links are not yet working properly and (2) for broken frames the number is not always correct. So, still working on it.

** Solved:** Ok. *Now* it works. The issue was that you have to use.

```
  \PassOptionsToPackage{backref=page}{hyperref}
```